# What is know about Baal Hammon's Vegetal Crown

Tags: religion, art, carthage

What more is known about the [Vegetal Crown](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=AOlYDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA270&lpg=PA270&dq=baal%20hammon%20%22crown%22&source=bl&ots=xIFS5Sy2wM&sig=elJE8G-IqdbjfT3alBMMg2KJcg4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEwbKT0-HcAhWQFogKHcsCBLkQ6AEwDnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=baal%20hammon%20%22crown%22&f=false) of the Carthaginian chief god [Baal Hammon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal_Hammon)?

I've searched for more information about this particular motif but can't find any.

Obviously it can be thought of as a fecundity/fertility symbol, but apart from that, what is it's origin? Are there any examples of other gods having vegetal crowns? Was it inspired by the [Modius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modius_(headdress)) of the Egyptian goddess Mut? Is there a specific vegetable that is depicted (in the same way that the [Acanthus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acanthus_(ornament)) and [Palmette](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmette) inspired certain designs)? Are there examples of pre- or post-Phoenician gods having actual vegetal crowns (and not merely other Modius like that worn by Serapis)?

[image]
[image]

- Vegetal Crown is a term I've never heard of before and came across in the article *"Gods, Masks, and Monstra"* by Matthew M. McCarty, in the book *"Beyond Boundaries: Connecting Visual Cultures in the Provinces of Ancient Rome"*, pg. 270

Comment: What is the source for calling this a "vegetal crown" - the word isn't used in the source you cite. I'd never heard the term; easy enough to infer what it means, but since you are asking for information about this object, we need to know where you found the term, so you don't get 100 people sending you back to the same source you used.

Comment: A source [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=AOlYDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA270&dq=Baal+Hammon+radiate+crown+vegetal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig0p2crubcAhWIsaQKHUKgDjcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Baal%20Hammon%20radiate%20crown%20vegetal&f=false) discusses this term for this crown, also referring to it as a 'radiate' crown.